# Asserting the user is logged in from the front-end via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, backbone.js, devise

My problem is as follows:

I have a rails (3.2.8) application that uses devise for authentication. Rails is just a RESTful api and the front-end is a backbone one-page app.

I manage to register and sign-in users, but how can the front-end get that information from the back-end with AJAX ? Basically I want to be able to tell from the front end that this user is logged in and has a session, or tell that the user has not logged in.

Currently I my controllers and models are completely rails-created, I have not touched them.

Googling around produced many tutorials that use the token_authenticatable module, but they had varying implementations and did not offer a explicit solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is let rails handle your sessions. You do this by:

```
rails generate session_migration
rake db:migrate
```

Then, store a session value in rails for example:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

(where user is an object of your User class)

And then you can constantly ping your rails backend via ajax to check whether the session[:user_id] variable is not null, if it isn't null then a session exists.